# Pneumatic Motor vs Heat Engine

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I noticed Wikipedia has separate articles for Pneumatic Motors and Heat Engines, however, given the relationship between temperature and pressure, aren't Pneumatic Motors just a subset of Heat Engines? Specifically, any open(as in open system) heat engine is capable of being run as a Pneumatic Motor, and visa versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy transfer in a pneumatic motor doesn't necessarily require heat transfer to effectively operate, although in practice this does happen. The larger effects are due to momentum exchange; air molecules transferring momentum to the pneumatic impellar.

Comment: docscience, BTW did you ever get a satisfactory exposition on the topic of equations of state? i seem to recall you asked about this some time ago?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Maybe. I had maybe 3 different questions regarding that topic.

Comment: How about the second part. Are all open heat Engines capable of being run as Pneumatic Motors and visa versa?

Comment: @JosephPyott I don't believe I can answer that question with certainty but my hunch is *no*. By *open* heat energy do you consider that both energy and *mass* flow can cross your control volume (system) boundary?